# Mathematical error with addition - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, radio-button, concatenation, addition

Morning,

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $('input:radio[name=opcja1]').change(function(){
     wynik =  $(this).val() * $('#liczba1').val() + $(this).val()
     $('.wynik').html(wynik);         
   });
});
</script>
```

I would like to do something like: *value of radio* * *#liczba1* + *value of radio* (or anything different). Now instead of 3*1+3=6 I getting 33. What should I do?

Comment: You're working with strings, not numbers, as an elements value is always a string. you have to parse the strings as numbers to add them

Comment: try to convert your value from string to int (use parseInt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecast the values to numbers :

```
var wynik = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($('#liczba1').val()) + parseInt($(this).val())
```

or use `parseFloat` instead.

As it is now you are concatenating strings. `'3'`+`'3'` == `'33'`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With your code I finished my project :)